# How to handle CollectionView Selection problem?

Tags: swift, collectionview

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtSij.png) [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VEQn.png)I'm trying to make a collection view that has a cyan background when selected. But when I select the first one it turns blue elsewhere. For example, when I select the first cell, the first cell becomes cyan, but even though I do not select the other indexes, one cell turns blue in every 3 indexes and it goes like this, how can I solve it.

```
   
var lastIndex: IndexPath = [1, 0]
enter image description here
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? LocationViewCell
        cell?.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        
        print(indexPath)
        
        if self.lastIndex != indexPath{
            cell?.backView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        }
        let cell2 = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.lastIndex) as? LocationViewCell
        

        cell2?.backView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        self.lastIndex = indexPath

      
        
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting the color of each cell correctly in the cellForItemAt method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "didSelectItemAt" method to control selected cells and "didDeselectItemAt" method for rest of the cells. I am giving a demo code here, which may help you.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LocationViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LocationViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // All the cell will have white background by default
    }
    
    // For selected cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // Selcted cell will have cyan bakground
    }
    
    // For not selected cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Rest of the cells, which are not selected will have white background
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of `dequeueReusableCell` as it always reuses cells. What I mean is when you scroll to right side it uses the cells used in the left side which had been scrolled. Thus it is showing you the green cells that are left behind.

So to solve this issue you have to go to your `LocationViewCell` and this piece of code,

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        backView.backgroundColor = .white
}
```